# Icon or text for "home" in a breadcrumb?

Tags: navigation, consistency, breadcrumbs, visual-cues

What is a better way to convey the home position in a breadcrumb - "home" as text or an icon representing a home?

An argument for the sake of an icon would be that a picture is easier to perceive than text and that it is understandable across all languages. The text on the other hand keeps consistency with the rest of the breadcrumb which is also text.

Comment: ...or both. Also, an icon may transcend language, but not necessarily culture.

Answer (score 2):

Text is always better for usability than just an icon. It is more accessible, understood more easily. The only advantages are space considertions and scannability. Sometimes they are also understood the same between different languages, but this can be [a trap](https://symbolsage.com/symbols-that-changed-meaning-over-time/) - you'd be surprised how different the perception for the same symbol can be in different cultures. But you should always make sure it's understood properly and provides ways to decipher it.

My process usually is as follows:

- **Text only** should be the default go to option;
- **Icon** + **Text** can be the best option, if the texts need to be scannable (if the users need to be able to find it fast among other texts) and the icons are not confusing, but make sure not to overdo it;
- **Icon only** is guaranteed worst option, use it only if you must (like if you have severe space deficit) or if you're absolutely sure there will be no misundertandings (for example, in a toolbar among other common options). And also remember to always provide accessibility and definition options (like tooltips that describe the meaning of the icon)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the "home" text is the best for the user to easily understand, Home icon has a universal meaning but with text keep consistency across the breadcrumb component.

Comment: What usability test would you suggest to prove that statement?

Comment: Anyone who tells you they can design a usability test to "prove" something like that is lying. A thought experiment shows if somebody doesn't know what the home icon means, a label they can read that says what the icon is will do better than one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target audience; if you're looking for people who are more tech-savvy, using the home as an icon is fine. However, if you are targeting elderly people or others who are resistant to new technology, it may be difficult for them to understand what the icon represents. I recently experienced this scenario with my uncel when he saw the reward icon on their Windows os lock screen and thought he made a few mistakes because the people/user icon appeared inverted.

[image]

If you go with the icon approach, I recommend using a tooltip so that when the user hovers over the icon, they can understand what it represents.

Comment: On the contrary, I contend "tech-savvy", "elderly people", and "resistant to new technology", are misdirected UX stereotypes. When it comes to interpreting symbols and brief referential phrases (such as "Home") there are similar bell curves of interpretation throughout each group. So rather than over-generalize users, build a behavioral outline with metrics collected from observational testing of a representative sample of users.

Answer (score -1):

Neither

Unless there's a good reason to put "home" as a breadcrumb.

**Example 1 - "Oh no, can't find home!"**

**Breadcrumbs in Amazon shopping:**

[image: breadcrumbs in amazon shopping]

if you do - remember it's mainly for the bots, since users push the site's logo to go home. I don't deal with bot experience but I'll go with WYSIWYG and use plain text in breadcrumbs as a rule of thumb

**Example 2 - "Ah! Home at last"**

**Breadcrumbs in UX stack exchange:**

[image: breadcrumbs in stack exchange]

Comment: The "Home" text in Stackexchange is just one single link, it is not a breadcrumb showing the path to where you are now. Btw, I have never ever noticed it so far. Maybe because it is useless staying that way alone, without the breadcrumb.